# cloning windows server 2008 OS drive to smaller drive using Robocopy

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, robocopy, disk-image

I'd like to clone a bootable OS disk using robocopy. The source drive is larger than the destination, but with plenty of free space.

Is it possible, and if it is, what do I need to keep in mind to get it to work?

So far I've booted to the install disk recovery environment and done a simple robocopy /mir, but I assume I need to fix the MBR and perhaps fiddle with the partition scheme as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using clonezilla would be easier.

Comment: indeed! I ended up using partmagic which have many of the same cloning features. I had to fiddle a lot with repairs (mbr etc) so it would be very interesting to know if it could be done with plain robocopy+repairs....

Comment: I think the full procedure would be to first shrink the source partition to the target size (with gparted) and then copy the whole disk (with the mbr) to the second smaller disk (with clonezilla). If you copy the whole disk you shouldn't have to worry about the mbr, but with windows you never know.